# Sporadic: The file '.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, precompiled

Symptoms: ASP.NET MVC website sporadically crashes and all .cshtml pages requests fail with this error. The problem seems random and happens once or twice a month. The site may run for months with no issues then out of the blue it will stop serving any .cshtml pages and gives the error on every .cshtml page request. A restart of the website is the only solution (or redeploy, which causes the same thing).

This was a very difficult problem to debug since it was so sporadic and none of the other answers I found helped, they did not address the problem where the site would deploy and run for long periods of time then crash with this error seemingly randomly. In the end I got some help from Microsoft.

I have .NET Framework 4.6.2 on windows server 2016

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. So which one is your question?

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about your MVC application and your server environment? Do you used a server fram or else? Do you add third-party module for your web application?

Comment: The issue has been resolved when i updated to .net framework 4.8